# jQuery validation not working - jqueryvalidation.org

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using http://jqueryvalidation.org

This works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/xs5vrrso/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But it doesn't work when I change the form to be in separate parts like this
http://jsfiddle.net/xs5vrrso/578/ (when I click submit it submits the form even though there is a blank required field)

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xs5vrrso/579/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is by default the validator will ignore hidden input elements from validation.

When you are go to the part 2, part 1 is hidden so the input fields inside it are also hidden so the validator is ignoring that.

You can use the `ignore` option to override this setting, but a better solution will be is to validate the fields before you move to a new part like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('valid form submitted');
            return false;
        }
    });

});

$("#next-btn").click(function () {
    if ($('#signup-part-1 :input').valid()) {
        $('#signup-part-1').hide();
        $('#signup-part-2').show();
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
      field1: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('valid form submitted');
      return false;
    }
  });

});

$("#next-btn").click(function() {
  if ($('#signup-part-1 :input').valid()) {
    $('#signup-part-1').hide();
    $('#signup-part-2').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#signup-part-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <div id="signup-part-1">PART 1
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary pull-right" id="next-btn">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="signup-part-2">PART 2
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Next

type is wrong, should be "submit"

Comment: it's not a submit button